# Need d3 brush to NOT work on touch devices

Tags: javascript, d3.js, touch, mouse

I'm implementing d3's brush behavior based on [Mike Bostock's code here.](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/f48fcdb929a620ed97877e4678ab15e6)
[jsfiddle version](https://jsfiddle.net/qyb47pqy/)

I'd like brush to work only with mouse events and NOT with touch events. I tried this:

```
function brushended() {
    if (d3.event.sourceEvent && d3.event.sourceEvent.type != "mouseup") return; 
    // Code for zooming
    // ...
}
```

Touch now creates the brush rectangle but doesn't do anything further. So, my objective is half-achieved. This is what I'd like to have: on touch devices, brush should be completely ignored and touch should perform its default behavior (e.g. touchmove for scrolling, two-finger for zooming).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a filter for your `brush`:

```
var brush = d3.brush().filter(() => event instanceof MouseEvent).on("end", brushended)
```

This will only activate the brush for `MouseEvent` and ignore `TouchEvent`

Comment: Fantastic. I tried so many different things without success – why did I not see this in the documentation? (rhet. ques.)